# Calculating Several Percentages from Record statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server

In short: I want to calculate multiple percentages based on the status of a record in another table.

In long: Hi all, the issue I'm having is that I'm trying to calculate a bunch of percentages based on how many tests were and were not administered of the total possible, and of those, how many were Completed/Declined for reporting reasons and I'm not sure the best way to do that.

For example, I have two major tables in play:

`Assessment
+---------------+--------+---------+---------+
| Assessment_ID |  Date  | Test_FK | Dept_FK |
+---------------+--------+---------+---------+
|             1 | 1/1/18 |       1 |       1 |
|             2 | 1/1/18 |       2 |       1 |
|             3 | 1/2/18 |       3 |       1 |
|             4 | 1/4/18 |       4 |       2 |
|             5 | 1/2/18 |       5 |       2 |
|             6 | 1/2/18 |       6 |       2 |
|             7 | 1/3/18 |       7 |       2 |
+---------------+--------+---------+---------+`

`Test
+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
| Test_ID | IsAdministered | IsComplete | IsDeclined |
+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
|       1 |              1 |          1 |          0 |
|       2 |              1 |          0 |          1 |
|       3 |              1 |          1 |          0 |
|       4 |              1 |          1 |          0 |
|       5 |              1 |          0 |          1 |
|       6 |              0 |          0 |          0 |
|       7 |              0 |          0 |          0 |
+---------+----------------+------------+------------+`

... not a real key factor but I wanted to mention this one as it weeds out Tests that may be falsely attributed to a different department...

`Assessment_Test_Eligbility_Lookup
+---------+-----------+----------+
| Dept_FK | DateStart | DateEnd  |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | 1/1/2017  | 1/1/2020 |
|       2 | 1/1/2017  | 1/1/2020 |
+---------+-----------+----------+`

... with the lookup table keeping track of which assessments are would have been eligible for a test to be taken. From here, I want to of the following:

```
SELECT
    dept.name,
    CONCAT(MONTH(enc.Encounter_Date), '-', YEAR(enc.Encounter_Date)),
    COUNT(Tests.IsAdministered = 1) / COUNT(Tests) 'Administered %',
    COUNT(Tests.IsComplete = 1) / COUNT(Tests.IsAdministered = 1) 'Completed %',
    COUNT(Tests.IsDeclined = 1) / COUNT(Tests.IsAdministered = 1) 'Declined %'
FROM
    DEPT
    JOIN Assessment ON Dept_ID = Dept_FK
    JOIN Test ON Test_ID = Test_FK
    JOIN Assessment_Test_Eligability_Lookup ON Dept_ID = Dept_FK 
       AND Date BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd
```

Unfortunately, after this, I'm not sure how best to proceed. Most because the look up table is rather large and joining on it multiple times might take an age to complete.

Expected output example:

```
+---------+------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Dept_ID | Month/Year | Total Possible | Administered % | Completed % of Admin | Declined % of Admin |
+---------+------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|       1 | 1-2018     |              3 |            100 |                   66 |                  33 |
|       2 | 1-2018     |              4 |             50 |                   50 |                  50 |
+---------+------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Any thoughts on this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We really need some more information here. That table structure, some sample data and the desired output based on the sample data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ BTW, there is no 'a' in eligibility. :)

Comment: made some edits. should be better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ways to do things like this with some sample data. Make sure to handle your divide by zero errors!

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (Encounter_Date datetime, IsAdministered bit, IsComplete bit, IsDeclined bit)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 10, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 9, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 8, 1, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 7, 1, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 6, 1, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 5, 1, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 4, 1, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 3, 1, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 2, 1, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (GETDATE() - 1, 1, 0, 1)

SELECT
CONCAT(MONTH(Encounter_Date), '-', YEAR(Encounter_Date)) AS "Month / Year",
AVG(CAST(IsAdministered AS NUMERIC(3,2))) 'Administered %',
CAST(COUNT(NULLIF(IsComplete, 0)) AS NUMERIC(3,2)) 
    / CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN IsAdministered = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS NUMERIC(3,2)) AS 'Completed %',
SUM(CAST(IsDeclined AS NUMERIC(3,2)))
    / SUM(CAST(IsAdministered AS NUMERIC(3,2))) AS 'Declined %'
FROM @Test
GROUP BY MONTH(Encounter_Date), YEAR(Encounter_Date)
```

Outputs:

```
Month / Year    Administered %  Completed % Declined %
1-2018          0.800000        0.500000    0.250000
```

Your sample DDL doesn't show a column named Encounter_Date, and your query doesn't have a table aliased as Tests, but if you fix up the table aliases, this is your query:

```
SELECT
    dept.Name,
    CONCAT(MONTH(Encounter_Date), '-', YEAR(Encounter_Date)) AS 'Month/Year',
    CAST(COUNT(NULLIF(Test.IsAdministered, 0)) AS NUMERIC(3,2))  / COUNT(*) 'Administered %',
    CAST(COUNT(NULLIF(Test.IsComplete, 0)) AS NUMERIC(3,2))  / COUNT(NULLIF(Test.IsAdministered, 0)) 'Completed %',
    CAST(COUNT(NULLIF(Test.IsDeclined, 0)) AS NUMERIC(3,2))  / COUNT(NULLIF(Test.IsAdministered, 0)) 'Declined %'
FROM
    DEPT
    JOIN Assessment ON Dept_ID = Dept_FK
    JOIN Test ON Test_ID = Test_FK
    JOIN Assessment_Test_Eligibility_Lookup ON Dept_ID = Assessment_Test_Eligibility_Lookup.Dept_FK 
       AND Encounter_Date BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd
GROUP BY Dept.Name, MONTH(Encounter_Date), YEAR(Encounter_Date)
```

Outputs:

```
Name    Month/Year  Administered %  Completed % Declined %
Dept 1  1-2018      1.00            0.66      0.33
Dept 2  1-2018      0.50            0.500     0.50
```

Comment: You're answer gave me the jump start I needed. My biggest issue was how best to filter the tests by status and the case statements take take of that. Thank you very much!